# kibana v4 how to visualize metrics meter

Tags: kibana, metrics, visualize, meter

I'm using com.codahale.metrics to feed an index metrics in elastic.
I have several meters (a type meter in metrics) wich difer with the field name.
I would like to have one graph per meter on count field. 
Actually, I only have a global count of all meters. I'm new with kibana so perhaps it's simple to visualize ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found it after some weeks, so I share for others...
First, isolate your meters in "discover" for example by name
in the search box, write name:*meter  (in my case, by convention, all meters finish by meter).. save
Second, in "analyze", choose the first visualisation "area chart"
The tip is to have subquery on different "terms" diven by "name"
X-axis: agregation:date histogram,field:@timestamp, interval: (choose minute or hour or day for dayly reports)
.. add_buckets:split area, sub agregation:terms, field:name, order by :count
Thats's it !!!